# How to use ByteData and ByteBuffer in flutter without mirror package

Tags: dart, udp, flutter

I am trying to develop a UDP application that receives data and converts the bytes into different data types.

I have the code below that works when using Dart on its own.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:mirror';

RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4, 20777).then((RawDatagramSocket socket){
  socket.listen((RawSocketEvent e){
    Datagram d = socket.receive();
    if (d == null) return;
    ByteBuffer buffer = d.data.buffer;
    DKByteData data = new DKByteData(buffer);
    exit(0);
  });
});
```

The only issue is when I try to run it inside my Flutter application, VS code gives me an error at `d.data.buffer` saying `The getter 'buffer' isn't defined for the class 'List<int>'.`

`import dart:mirror;` does not seem to work in flutter and [this page](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/1150) says that dart mirrors is blocked in Flutter.

As I cannot import dart mirror in order to get a Bytebuffer from a Datagram socket, how else am I able to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type of `d.data` is plain `List<int>`, not `Uint8List`. A `List` does not have a `buffer` getter, so the type system complains.

If you know that the value is indeed `Uint8List` or other typed-data, you can cast it before using it:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = (d.data as Uint8List).buffer;
```

Also be aware that a `Uint8List` doesn't necessarily use its entire buffer. Maybe do something like:

```
Uint8List bytes = d.data;
DKByteData data = new DKByteData(bytes.buffer, bytes.offsetInBytes, bytes.lengthInBytes);
```

if possible, and if `DKByteData` doesn't support that, you might want to allocate a new buffer in the case where the data doesn't fill the buffer:

```
Uint8List bytes = d.data;
if (bytes.lengthInBytes != bytes.buffer.lengthInBytes) {
  bytes = Uint8List.fromList(bytes);
}
DKByteData data = new DKByteData(bytes.buffer);
```

Comment: If I were to do `DKByteData data = DKByteData(Uint8List.fromList(d.data).buffer);`, would that guarantee that I get all the bytes as I'm simply skipping your check and getting the UInt8List.fromList straight away? This is what I found out before you posted. You have more useful information then what I found though. I just found out 'how'. You have told me 'why' and some warnings too.

Comment: Yes, that would always get you all the bytes of the original list. It will copy the bytes to a new buffer, even when the original buffer would have sufficed, so you will get an extra overhead.