# how to Split Files and Integrate it in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, split, blockchain

I need to make app to upload and download files

when user upload for example "file.mp4" if this size more then 1MB i will Split it or Chunked it to Simmler files in like [500kb , 500kb] and upload first 500kb in server and secound 500kb to scound server then when will download this files again i need to integrate [500kb + 500kb] = 1MB 
and show file 1MB like first time

Comment: Yes. Ok. And what is the problem ? Any questions?

Comment: @blackapps yes how to do this  ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though you've already stated a method to approach your particular problem. Here is a link to another question that is somewhat [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801051/how-to-use-bytedata-and-bytebuffer-in-flutter-without-mirror-package). Learning the buffer process and how to implement it would be a start.

Hope that's useful.